# Clustering with multiple metrics in Matlab

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, categorical-data

I have a data set that contains both categorical and numerical features for each row. I would like to select a different similarity metric for each feature (column) and preform hierarchical clustering on the data. Is there a way to do that in Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is actually fairly straightforward: `linkage`, which creates the tree, takes as input a dissimilarity matrix. Consequently, in the example workflow below

```
Y = pdist(X,'cityblock');
Z = linkage(Y,'average');
T = cluster(Z,'cutoff')
```

you simply replace the call to `pdist` with a call to your own function that calculates the pairwise dissimilarity between rows, everything else stays the same.